# Optimum way to make an auto back up of photos on server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

What I've known:

- How make requests to server for uploading I will use `AFNetworking`
- How access photos and videos with help of `ALAssetsLibrary`
- I think I must use `CoreData` to keep info about:last syncing, photos already uploaded, etc. I worked already with coreData it will no be a problem.

My problems are **logic**, **flow** how can achieve this auto back up and of course to be **optimum(minimum requests, short way)**. What steps must follow to achieve this scope?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I think CoreData is too heavy in this situation. You may want to use plist to store your info data .here are some steps to follow .

1. After loading image from server, create a dictionary to store the message you want and create another dictionary to store these messages , and use image's url as the key of this dictionary. It might look like this:

   ```
   imageUrl = {
         lastSyncTime = xxxxxxxxxx,
         photoUploaded = 0,
      }
   ```
2. Create a plist file to save this dictionary:

   ```
    - (NSString *)filePath:(NSString *) fileName{
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
       return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    }
      [yourImageDictionary writeToFile:[self filePath:@"imageInfo.plist"] atomically:YES];
   ```
3. Read or write your plist file anytime you want:

   ```
   if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self filePath:@"imageInfo.plist"]]) {
       NSDictionary *imageInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[self filePath:@"imageInfo.plist"]];
   }
   ```